# IAB consumePurchase() no longer works for static response android.test.purchased

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Our beta app uses `android.test.purchased` so customers can test for free. But recently something broke with consuming these test products. The purchase process still works fine but when we try to consume:

```
int response = ms.consumePurchase(3, mContext.getPackageName(), token);
```

This now always returns `RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR == 5`. The data passed appears valid, token is `inapp:com.lootworks.swords:android.test.purchased` which I think is correct for the static test products.

Simultaneously all our earlier app versions also stopped working and we did not change our code, so it sure seems like something changed with IAB itself.

I also tested purchase/consume of the real (for $) products and it succeeds with the same code. So the consume problem seems to affect only the static response test item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Sean's help and some additional testing this appears to be a google play IAB regression. Have opened a bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53077

Comment: This began working again on 3/14/13 (pi day :). Like before I changed nothing so I assume google did a fix

Comment: so what's the fix? i still see it happening from time to time with the newest version of the library...

Answer (score 2):

My team and I are experiencing this same issue.  Nothing has changed with the app consume code, so it is very strange.  The app is not release-ready yet, so we have plenty else to work on, but this throws a monkey wrench into testing for sure.

This may not be an option for you, but you could change the namespace, delete the app entry in the dev console and go through the process of making a new one, and splitting the key up again, etc.

I only suggest this because this problem does not seem to be happening for all apps.  Anyway, if the consume in our app does not start magically working again soon, this is what we will try.

Comment: We = the app development team I work with.  'We' are having the same problem as the original poster with one of the apps we are working on.  I thought that was obvious, but perhaps not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, thought it was clear and it is very helpful to get a confirmation from another developer. Because we have a lot of installed users I think we may have to hack up a new release that bypasses the IAB purchase flow completely while we wait for either a fix from Google (if it is a gplay regression) or some work-around or fix in our code. Right now I can't see much else to do as the call to consumePurchase() is pretty simple, can't even see a programmatic alternative to try.

Comment: I am quite sure something has changed gplay serverside.  We did a complete code reversion to 4 days ago when the consume was definitely working, and it is providing the same result: 5:Developer Error.

Nothing to do but wait for a fix.  And if no fix is forthcoming, we will be changing the namespace, rebuilding and resubmitting the app for a new key.

Comment: I agree with you that gplay seems to be the problem. Have you been able to confirm that a new key/namespace is a permanent fix? We can successfully do purchase+consume with our existing namespace+key if we use real IAB products instead of the static test products; I would have thought that a namespace or key problem would affect that also.

Comment: That is a good point.  We have not gotten to the point of testing real IAB items yet with the affected app, so perhaps it is only a problem with the test service... in which case there really is nothing to do but wait.  However, as I said before, not all apps are affected, so perhaps doing the suggested procedure would actually have an effect.

When we get to the point that we are ready to try it, I will post the results (unless you post yours first).

Comment: For us it is moot anyway as we need to fix installed users. If I don't see some enthusiastic googler join the thread (on a Sunday? :) I'll remove the static test item flow from our beta. We'll lose the veracity of the full gplay purchase flow but right now it's just plain busted

Comment: I can confirm this problem too. This is really a pain in the rear end... I hope this will be solved soon.